# How to display comments or sub records in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to display comments or sub records in **Reactjs.**

I have the following code which displays posts from an array via **reactjs**. please  how do I display the comment as well.

With **Angularjs**, I can easily achieve this with the code below

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <div>
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

                    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
                        <div class="comment">{{ comment.comment }}</div>
                     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the main code in **Reactjs**. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
{"id":"1","content":"first post","comments":[{"comment":"first comment"}]},
{"id":"2","content":"second post","comments":[{"comment":"second comment"}]}
],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>Records</h3>
      <ul> 
        {this.state.rec.map((post, i) => ( 
        <li key = {i}>
          {post.id} - {post.content}
        </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Application /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: `post.comments.map(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to do this:

```js
const Post = (props) => {
  return (<React.Fragment><li >
          {props.post.id} - {props.post.content}
        </li>
        <div>
        {props.post.comments.map((comment, i) => (<div>{comment.comment}</div>))}
        </div>
        </React.Fragment>
        );

};
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
{"id":"1","content":"first post","comments":[{"comment":"first comment"}]},
{"id":"2","content":"second post","comments":[{"comment":"second comment"}, {"comment":"third comment"}]}
],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>Records</h3>
      <ul> 
        {this.state.rec.map((post, i) => ( 
        <Post post={post} key={i}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Application /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and God bless you Sir Ryan.